# PostGIS "thresholded intersect" or "signfiicant intersect" query

Tags: postgis, intersection

I've been working an application using PostGIS that needs to join the interior intersection of two different layers (made up of polygons and multipolygons).  These layers have many shapes which are perfectly touching each other.

In the past I was using the interior intersect version of the `st_relate` query but with recent data set updates I have begun to see false positive for intersects where its detecting microscopic intersections between layers seemingly due to float point errors.  The issue is exacerbated when I use shapes that have been converted to and from geojson.

Ideally I don't want to find all the intersecting but only find the "significant" or non infinitesimally small intersects.

I've tried the following:

- st_relate but '2********' instead 'T********' but I'm still seeing the issue.
- a thresholded intersection area ratio join using `st_area(st_intersection(A, B)) / st_area(A) > Threshold` condition.  This work really well and more closely matches the actual logic I'm modelling. However my measuring has shown this to be at least 4 times slower than the `st_relate` query even when I cut the search space significantly with a bounding box intersection.
- st_snaptogrid to try and overcome floating point errors but I'm finding neighbours with interpolated points like below are showing up as intersections.

[image]

Is there a performant way of finding "significant" intersections in PostGIS.  I don't really need to know the intersection ratio or anything like that and significant could be a very broad range.

Alternatively is there a way to use st_snaptogrid and handle cases like the image above.

Comment: Perhaps the new Overlay NG https://blog.crunchydata.com/blog/waiting-for-postgis-3.1-geos-3.9 will help with the pretty common problem that you have.

Comment: Your "thresholded intersection area ratio" is probably the best that you can do with PostGiS now.