# Checking if two polygons have internal points in common with GeoDjango and PostGIS

Tags: postgis, polygon, overlapping-features, geodjango

I am using GeoDjango with the PostGIS backend. Given two polygons I want to check if they overlap. I mean, they have interior points in common.
If we check

```
A.function(B)
```

In the following picture "Example 1" would be False, "Example 2", would be False (cause they only have edges in common) and "Example 3" Would be True, cause they have interior points in common

[image: Examples]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `st_intersects` with `st_touches` to find polygons that overlap:

```
select st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom) and not st_touches(a.geom,b.geom) as overlap
from polygon_a a, polygon_b b;
```

Returns true if polygons share interior points returns false if polygons only share a boundary or do not intersect.

Answer (score 5):

Use `ST_Overlaps` function: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Overlaps.html

```sql
WHERE ST_Overlaps(a.geom, b.geom)
```

> Returns TRUE if geometry A and B "spatially overlap". Two geometries
> overlap if they have the same dimension, each has at least one point
> not shared by the other (or equivalently neither covers the other),
> and the intersection of their interiors has the same dimension. The
> overlaps relationship is symmetrical.

Comment: `ST_Overlaps` requires that the two arguments have points that are NOT in common. So it doesn't detect polygons which are fully covered by another one.

Answer (score 1):

Since `ST_Intersects` would return True for example 2, I don't think there is a predefined operation in PostGIS to do what you want so you get to explore the world of the [Dimensionally Extended 9-Intersection Model](https://Dimensionally%20Extended%209-Intersection%20Model).

So you want Interior to Interior as the result of a `ST_Relate` function call, which I think is going to be something like:

```
WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
  AND ST_Relate(a.geom, b.geom, '2********')
```

So there has to be an intersection but the result must be of dimension 2 (i.e. a polygon not a line).

Comment: You can also use a DE9IM mask of `T********` (which is equivalent for areas).

Comment: See this question for a potential robustness issue to be aware of: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/407520/postgis-thresholded-intersect-or-signfiicant-intersect-query